# How to animate two divs in html / css to make a semi-circle transition?

Tags: html, css

I make this css/html logo, and it has 2 semi-circles, I want to animate them... I want they "change" postion, but not making a linear moviment, I want a semi-circle transition

Can anyone help me? A suggestion?

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
  <div class="halfCircle right"></div>
  <div class="name">
    <h1>Regulus</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="halfCircle left"></div>
```

Here is: http://jsfiddle.net/6cY7x/

Comment: How exactly do you want them to move? Away from the center at separate angles?

Comment: I want to animate them around the title, making a semi-circle moviment, and stopping in the place there is the other div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I went about it. Instead of rotating the `.halfCircle`s individually, I put them in a container as big as the logo. The logo itself I gave 60px of padding on the top and bottom to give space for the `.halfCircle`s around the text.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
  <div class="Circle">
    <div class="halfCircle right"></div>
    <div class="halfCircle left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <h1>Regulus</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.logo{
  width:150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.Circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: all 800ms ease-out;
}
```

The half circles are then positioned absolute to their spots, instead of with `float` and `margin`. This will make it easier to adjust and scale the logo later.

```
.halfCircle{
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 27.5px;
  border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
  background: black;
}
.right{
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform:rotate(55deg);
}

.left{
  transform:rotate(-125deg);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Then, on `:hover`, we just rotate the `.Circle` element 180deg and presto! No magic numbers, just a simple half rotation.

```
.logo:hover .Circle {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/Hrlqx

Answer (score 2):

Here is the CSS

```
.halfCircle{
     height:60px;
     width:27.5px;
     border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
    background:black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s; 
}
.right{
  transform:rotate(55deg)  translateY(70px);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(55deg)  translateY(70px); 
}
.left{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-125deg)  translateY(70px); 
    transform:rotate(-125deg) translateY(70px);
}
.logo:hover .right {
    transform:rotate(235deg)  translateY(70px);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(235deg)  translateY(70px); 
}
.logo:hover .left{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(55deg)  translateY(70px); 
    transform:rotate(55deg) translateY(70px);
}

.logo{
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}

.name h1{
  font-family: serif;
  margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6cY7x/1/)